# Object is not subscriptable while filtering a GET request

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

I am using requests on python to receive data from the twitch api. However, I only want some of the data, not all of it. I only want the `is_live` parenthisis. However, I am trying to do this by using:

`final = response["is_live"]`

This returns me the error:

> TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Is there a different way to filter the Get data?

Thanks, I will leave my code below:

````
import requests

headers = {
    'client-id': 'myclientid',
    'Authorization': 'my authorisation',
}

params = (
    ('query', 'Ninja'),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels', headers=headers, params=params)

final = response["is_live"]

print(final)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` method returns [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) object. You need to apply "filtering" on  [`text`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) field of it:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels', headers=headers, params=params)

final = response.text["is_live"]
```

Comment: Hi, this still presents me with the error ```AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'test'```

Comment: Im sorry, i made a typo